# Updating Data in MS Acces with VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

Can someone help me with my UPDATE syntax, I have checked the fieldnames ,my names of my textbox and single/double quotes (well im not sure I really looked that because im dumb), the system says I have syntax error but im not sure where the error is.

MY CODE:

```
Private Sub btnupdate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnupdate.Click


    Try
        con.Open()
        sql = "UPDATE Register SET LastName='" & LName.Text & "',Firstname='" & FName.Text & "',Adress='" & Address.Text & "',CellphoneNo=" & Val(CellNo.Text) & ",TelephoneNo=" & Val(TelNo.Text) & ",Email='" & Email.Text & "',PetName='" & PetName.Text & "',Specie='" & Specie.Text & "',Breed='" & Breed.Text & "',Weight=" & Val(Weight.Text) & ",Color='" & Color.Text & "',Gender='" & Gender.Text & "',Age=" & Val(Age.Text) & ",DiagnosisType='" & Diagnosis.Text & "',DateOfDiagnosis=" & Dates.Text & " WHERE ID=" & Val(Me.Text) & ""
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandText = sql

        i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
        If i > 0 Then
            MsgBox("Record has been UPDATED successfully!")

        Else
            MsgBox("No record has been UPDATED!")
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        con.Close()
        loadrecord()
    End Try
End Sub
```

My code doesnt seem secure but, it's fine because its only for a school project.

Any help would be appreciated THank you!!!!

Comment: `it's fine because its only for a school project` And that's exactly how bad habits get started. Do it right the first time, always, no matter the situation, and you won't end up doing it wrong multiple times.

Comment: Ineresting that if you make your code secure you will get rid of the syntax problem ;)

Comment: My first suggestion would be to run the SQL manually in Access, and get it right there.  Once you have some working code, replace all the values in visual studio.  Also using String.Format will also make your query more legible in visual studio as you no longer need to worry about concatenating strings.

Comment: I am totally new to VB.net so I do not know much about security But hopefully at my University they will teach us about it @InteXX

Comment: I have run it on MS ACCES , it runs fine but I do not really know why it doesnt work on Visual studio. @PhoenixStoneham

Comment: Thank you for your help guys, I have found the problem and it was on the Dates I needed to put Val because it deals with numbers. Thank you!!

Comment: Good security is language-agnostic. Its concepts and requirement apply to all languages and platforms, everywhere. The problem we're dealing with here is called [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Concatenating a SQL command directly from user input is very dangerous; you'll want to use parameterized queries instead. Validate the input data first, though—this gives you an opportunity to trap errors before they reach the SQL engine. Basically, it's best to assume at the very start of the design phase that you'll have malicious users entering data into your application.

Comment: Good catch on finding the problem. Good also for reporting it back here. Why not take the next step and enter it as an answer and accept it? This will help others down the road, as they'll be able to easily find your solution. (Also, take note of Fabio's good suggestion.)

Comment: well sure do next time if I make another post. Thank you :>